# Yammer Notes Migration

Tags: yammer

I'm trying to Migrate versions of documents along with their description and comments to Yammer. Yammer notes seem to support versions. Is there a REST endpoint for Yammer Notes ?If I cannot migrate as Yammer Notes how else would I be able to migrate versions of documents along with their description and comments to Yammer ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, there isn't an endpoint directly for Notes in Yammer.

In the Data Export API you can see what Notes are there, look for 'Pages' but you'll need to be or ask a verified admin to get that data. 
https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/data-export-api

But you cannot migrate the data *into* Yammer via this API.